# Error setting datatype for data template x:DataType="local:Data"

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

While setting datatype for data template in listview UWP I'm facing this issue

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error XDG0008 The name "Data" does not exist in the namespace
>   "using:datasample".

**Note:I have added namespace but doesn't work**

**xmlns:data="using:datasample"**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Datasam">
                <Grid Windows10FallCreatorsUpdate:ColumnSpacing="50">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Windows10FallCreatorsUpdate:Spacing="15" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding creatdate}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Windows10FallCreatorsUpdate:Spacing="10">
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

How to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I have used spacing inside the Grid in DataTemplate, when i removed that, it works

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Datasam">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding creatdate}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Assets/Icons/applogo.png"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build whole your project (Build -> Build Solution)
if it isn't work turn off vs at few minutes then open your project

If it isn't work , use "*local*" instead of data that you describe it above then build your project

Comment: nothing worked in my case,i have posted my answer below